# Neo4j - I have 2 collects where the data is related. How do I merge them together?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I feel like I'm doing a lot of extra work here because there's something I don't know that'll make it a lot easier!

[image]

So basically, I am trying to get the user's visitors, and who visited them.

1) This is the current query I'm using:

```
MATCH (you:User {user_id: { id }})
WITH you
OPTIONAL MATCH(you)-[yvr:VISIT]->(youVisited:User)
WITH you, collect(youVisited) as youVisited, collect(yvr) as yvr
OPTIONAL MATCH (visitedYou:User)-[vyr:VISIT]->(you)
WITH youVisited, collect(visitedYou) as visitedYou, collect(vyr) as vyr, yvr
RETURN
  youVisited,
  visitedYou,
  yvr,
  vyr,
  length(filter(m in vyr where m.seen = false)) as unseenCount
```

[image]
(bottom is cut off, but `youVisited` is to `yvr`, `visitedYou` is to `vyr`, right is cut off but `unseenCount` is there)

```
╒══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤═════════════╕
│"youVisited"                  │"visitedYou"                  │"yvr"                         │"vyr"                         │"unseenCount"│
╞══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪═════════════╡
│[{"user_id":"auth0|58784f52734│[{"user_id":"auth0|5865bfa8087│[{"created_at":1484294208011,"│[{"created_at":1484317325539,"│2            │
│b0307b61ea401"},{"user_id":"au│52725eaaae8f9"},{"user_id":"au│seen":false},{"created_at":148│seen":false},{"created_at":148│             │
│th0|587805cb995ac47e7dbe42ae"}│th0|587805cb995ac47e7dbe42ae"}│4294735987,"seen":false},{"cre│4321428350,"seen":false}]     │             │
│,{"user_id":"auth0|5865bfa8087│]                             │ated_at":1484293423029,"seen":│                              │             │
│52725eaaae8f9"},{"user_id":"au│                              │false},{"created_at":148429420│                              │             │
│th0|58669ac4d4aed25972f7c33e"}│                              │1140,"seen":false},{"created_a│                              │             │
│,{"user_id":"auth0|586a0337b94│                              │t":1484294214268,"seen":false}│                              │             │
│a4d77c1f77cb3"}]              │                              │]                             │                              │             │
└──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

2) So here's where I dunno what to do! **I want the get the `created_at` of the `youVisited`, `visitedYou` items, but I don't know how to merge them during the query**, so I end up making this mess:

```
  const nodes = {
    youVisited: row.get('youVisited').map((yv, index) => Object.assign(
      yv.properties,
      { created_at: row.get('yvr')[index].properties.created_at },
    )),
    visitedYou: row.get('visitedYou').map((vy, index) => Object.assign(
      vy.properties,
      { created_at: row.get('vyr')[index].properties.created_at },
    )),
    unseenCount: row.get('unseenCount'),
  };
```

3) Then I have to fetch other data and find map it again...

```
  const youVisitedPromises = nodes.youVisited.map(yv => usersIndex.getObject(yv.user_id));
  const visitedYouPromises = nodes.visitedYou.map(vy => usersIndex.getObject(vy.user_id));
  let [youVisited, visitedYou] = await Promise.all([
    youVisitedPromises, visitedYouPromises,
  ].map(Promise.all, Promise));

  youVisited = youVisited.map(yv => Object.assign(
    yv,
    { visited_at: _.get(_.find(nodes.youVisited, { user_id: yv.objectID }), 'created_at') },
  ));
  visitedYou = visitedYou.map(vy => Object.assign(
    vy,
    { visited_at: _.get(_.find(nodes.visitedYou, { user_id: vy.objectID }), 'created_at') },
  ));

  result = {
    youVisited,
    visitedYou,
    unseenCount: nodes.unseenCount,
  };
```

**I think this could be made much easier if I did something in step 1) where instead of RETURN two separate arrays that relate to each other e.g. `youVisited` to `yvr`, I just have one array with objects that contain all the data `youVisited: [{ user_id, created_at, seen }, ...]`. How do I do this with Neo4j?**

Expected final `result` that I need in the end looks something like:

```
  result = {
    youVisited: [{ user_id: 'a', nickname: 'foo', visited_at: 12931093 }, ...],
    visitedYou: [{ user_id: 'b', nickname: 'bar', visited_at: 12931099 }, ...],
    unseenCount: 1,
  };
```

Full code if there is anything else that can help:

```
  const cypherGetVisitors = `
    MATCH (you:User {user_id: { id }})
    WITH you
    OPTIONAL MATCH(you)-[yvr:VISIT]->(youVisited:User)
    WITH you, collect(youVisited) as youVisited, collect(yvr) as yvr
    OPTIONAL MATCH (visitedYou:User)-[vyr:VISIT]->(you)
    WITH youVisited, collect(visitedYou) as visitedYou, collect(vyr) as vyr, yvr
    RETURN
      youVisited,
      visitedYou,
      yvr,
      vyr,
      length(filter(m in vyr where m.seen = false)) as unseenCount
  `;
  const queryResult = await retry(this.connector._bolt._pool._maxIdle + 1, async () => {
    const session = this.connector.session();
    try {
      const res = await session.run(cypherGetVisitors, { id });
      session.close();
      return res;
    } catch (neo4jError) {
      throw new Error(neo4jError);
    }
  });
  const row = queryResult.records[0];
  const nodes = {
    youVisited: row.get('youVisited').map((yv, index) => Object.assign(
      yv.properties,
      { created_at: row.get('yvr')[index].properties.created_at },
    )),
    visitedYou: row.get('visitedYou').map((vy, index) => Object.assign(
      vy.properties,
      { created_at: row.get('vyr')[index].properties.created_at },
    )),
    unseenCount: row.get('unseenCount'),
  };

  const youVisitedPromises = nodes.youVisited.map(yv => usersIndex.getObject(yv.user_id));
  const visitedYouPromises = nodes.visitedYou.map(vy => usersIndex.getObject(vy.user_id));
  let [youVisited, visitedYou] = await Promise.all([
    youVisitedPromises, visitedYouPromises,
  ].map(Promise.all, Promise));

  youVisited = youVisited.map(yv => Object.assign(
    yv,
    { visited_at: _.get(_.find(nodes.youVisited, { user_id: yv.objectID }), 'created_at') },
  ));
  visitedYou = visitedYou.map(vy => Object.assign(
    vy,
    { visited_at: _.get(_.find(nodes.visitedYou, { user_id: vy.objectID }), 'created_at') },
  ));

  result = {
    youVisited,
    visitedYou,
    unseenCount: nodes.unseenCount,
  };
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? There are some features in 3.1.x that can help you out here, notably map projections.

Comment: I'm using 3.1! Also I just found out I can do this: `WITH you, collect({user_id: youVisited.user_id, created_at: yvr.created_at}) as youVisited` which might be all I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already have a solution that's working (using COLLECT() along with a new map of the values you want).

If you do happen to need all values + some more, you can use the 3.1 [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#_map_projection) feature, which can make it easier to include some or all properties of a node plus other properties you want to be present in the returned structure.

An example using a segment of your query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH(you)-[yvr:VISIT]->(youVisited:User)
WITH you, collect(youVisited {.*, created_at: yvr.created_at}) as youVisted
```

In this case the .* means to include all properties of the node (youVisited), but if you only need certain ones you can include only the relevant keys and the key/value pair will be included in the returned map. So if you only needed user_id and created_at, this would work:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH(you)-[yvr:VISIT]->(youVisited:User)
WITH you, collect(youVisited {.user_id, created_at: yvr.created_at}) as youVisted
```

Comment: Much cleaner, more flexible, powerful way of doing it, especially with the `.*` "just gimme the whole object, with some of this other stuff". More aligned with how I think about the problem too, like JavaScript ES6 spreading, haha. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that I can build an object during the collect. Any problems with this, or a better way to do it?

```
MATCH (you:User {user_id: { id }})
WITH you
OPTIONAL MATCH(you)-[yvr:VISIT]->(youVisited:User)
WITH you, collect({user_id: youVisited.user_id, created_at: yvr.created_at}) as youVisited
OPTIONAL MATCH (visitedYou:User)-[vyr:VISIT]->(you)
WITH youVisited, collect({user_id: visitedYou.user_id, created_at: vyr.created_at}) as visitedYou, collect(vyr) as vyr
RETURN
  youVisited,
  visitedYou,
  length(filter(m in vyr where m.seen = false)) as unseenCount
```

[image]

I still have to do all that other map stuff after I fetch the rest of the data from a different source, but that's not Neo4j related.